# Testcafe Page reload

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, page-refresh, testcafe

How I can reload the current page with testcafe? 
I found

```
.eval(() => location.reload(true))
```

But it looks like an old code, current TestCafe do not understand this. (No function error)

Answer (score 6):

It's the correct way to reload the tested page. 
See a full test example:

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `New Fixture`
    .page ('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/');

test('New Test', async t => {
    await t.typeText('#developer-name', 'Peter Parker');

    await t.eval(() => location.reload(true));

    await t
        .wait(3000)
        .expect(Selector('#developer-name').value).eql('');
});
```

Comment: are there any known side effects from using the overload of reload without the parameter, as the the one you have used is now deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to post this to all the `eval` answers of this question but got modded... hopefully I can add some more context lest people continue to do this wrong.

Don't use `eval`; the better way is to make use of [Testcafe's ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/clientfunction/) instead. I use something like this in my base page object:

```
  async refresh () {
    await ClientFunction(() => {
      document.location.reload();
    })();
  }
```

then in your test, call it with something like `myPage.refresh()`

Answer (score 0):

Simple and better solution is use the below code snippet to to re-load the page in testcafe.

```
await t.eval(() => location.reload(true));
```